# Colorful pixels showing on screen pi4

Tags: pi-4, screen, gpu

I just received a new Raspberry Pi 4 4GB version. From the time of the first boot, I have colorful pixels showing up in different places on the screen. I'm using an FHD 1920x1080 screen and I have tried both of the HDMIs on the pi. I'm using a microHDMI to HDMI converter cable. The HDMI connector that is the closest to the headphone jack works best. I've also tried setting different amounts of RAM on the GPU, but nothing works. At the moment I set it on 512MB. I tried editing the config.txt but it doesn't help. I'm using the official USB-C power supply. I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: I assume your using Raspbian was it installed with Noobs or flashed directly to sd card? I recommend the latter.

Comment: I have Raspbian Buster flashed directly to a microSD card.

Comment: What power supply?

Comment: The official USB-C power supply

Comment: What is the resolution of your screen? Hdmi socket next to power should be used? Is correct input selected on tv? Add all this info to your question.

Comment: If you can provide us with a screenshot, or a picture of the screen, that would be helpful. Also, are you using any adapters/long hdmi cords? Anything else abnormal about your setup?

Comment: I'm using a short microHDMI to HDMI cable. I'll send a picture as soon as possible.

Comment: How are you setting the gpu memory? Editing config.txt or ssh onto Pi. You could force the resolution.

Comment: Please add all the detailed informations from your comments to the question. You can [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/111658/edit) it.